# Javascript/groovy : how to create all possible words up to largest word?

Tags: javascript, groovy

I would like to create a function that creates letter combinations using the alphabet and numbers. I would like to do this in javascript or groovy. Here is where I am at, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    def characters = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H" , "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z", 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, "-", "_", "[", "]", "+", "^", "\", "-", "_", "[", "]", "+", "^", "\", "!", "@", "#", "$", "%", "*", "(", ")", "+", "<", ">", "|", "?", "/", "\", "`", "~", "œ", "∑", "´", "®", "†", "¥", "¨", "ˆ", "ø", "π", "å", "ß", "∂", "ƒ", "©", "˙", "∆", "k", "¬", "Ω", "≈", "ç", "√", "∫", "˜", "µ", "¡", "™", "£", "¢", "∞", "§", "7", "•", "ª", "º", "–", "≠", "“", "‘", "«", "…", "æ", "≤", "≥", "÷", "`", "⁄", "™",  "‹", "›", "ﬁ", "ﬂ", "‡", "°", "·", "‚", "—", "±", "Œ", "„", "´", "‰", "ˇ", "Á", "¨", "ˆ", "Ø", "∏", "”", "’", "«", "»", "Å", "Í", "Î", "Ï", "˝", "Ó", "Ô", "", "Ò", "Ú", "Æ", "¸", "˛", "Ç", "◊", "◊", "ı", "◊", "ı", "˜", "Â", "Â", "¯", "˘", "¿", "÷", "¡", "™", "£", "¢", "∞", "§", "¶", "•", "ª", "º", "–", "≠", "œ", "∑", "´", "®", "†", "¥", "¨", "ˆ", "ø", "π", "“", "‘", "«", "å", "ß", "∂", "ƒ", "©", "˙", "∆", "˚", "¬", "…", "æ", "Ω", "≈", "ç", "√", "∫", "˜", "µ", "≤", "≥", "÷", " " ]

    function create_words(){
        def word = ""
        def total_characters = 2
        create_word("a", 1)
    }

    function create_word(character, number){
        characters.each(){ le ->
            for(var n = 0; n < characters.size(); n++){
                def ch = characters[n]
                characters.each(){ letter ->
                    def word = letter + add_letter(ch, number)
                    words.add(word)
                    for(var c = number; c < number_times; c++){
                        create_word(character, c)
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!le.equals(" ")){
                create_word(characters.next(), 1)
            }   
        }
    }

    function add_letter(character, number){
        if(character == "a"){
            return "a" * number
        }
        return characters.next(character * number)
    }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The amount of time it would take to calculate all words up to 8 characters (the standard length of a password) is massive. You appear to be using all ASCII characters except the control characters. This leaves you with 224 characters. There are 6338465731314712576 strings that are 8 characters long using this character set. If you really want to go through with this I would recommend learning CUDA and getting one of [these](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/data-center/dgx-1/).

Comment: I did a check of how many characters you have, turns out you have 239, so there are 10645920227784266881 strings that are 8 characters long using this character set. Also if you are trying to produce strings and not words (which is apparent because you are using characters that would never be used in a word) you are probably trying to do a brute force attack. If that is so I'll save you the time, about half of the characters you have are not used in a password (the charset is 96 characters long for passwords), also just use HashCat.

Comment: This doesn't even compile in either JavaScript or Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy example that print all word combinations of selected length:

```
def characters = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
int WORD_LENGTH = 3
def combinationList = []

WORD_LENGTH.times{
   combinationList << characters
}

combinationList.combinations().each{
   println it.join()
}
```

Comment: For golfing: `def combinationList = (0..WORD_LENGTH).collect{characters}`